# Redirect from console window(C++ app) to textbox(C# app)

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, findwindow

I'm creatin application(C#) that need run another app. This. app is game(C++,Directx7,GDI, I don't have source) that show console window for debugging from dll(static).
For show console window this dll has this lines:

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONIN$","rb",stdin);   
freopen("CONOUT$","wb",stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$","wb",stderr);
```

In my c# app. i want hide console window and redirect text from console window to textbox.
For hide console window i'm using winapi **FindWindow**, **ShowWindow** is not problem. But how i can redirect text(output) from console window to textbox?

Comment: Let's assume you are starting your game from the command line. Will you see the expected output in the CL there you started your game?

Comment: yes, i see exprected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your game using following code:

```
     Process process = new Process();
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + pathToGame + "\"";
     //process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ReadOutput);
     process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ReadOutput);

     process.Start();
     process.BeginOutputReadLine();
     process.BeginErrorReadLine();

     //process.WaitForExit();
```

CL output and errors will go here

```
  private static void ReadOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Data != null)
     {
        //your output here
     }
  }
```

Comment: I'm already use this code. Is not work. Programm is stop when i'm setup breakpoint in ReadOutput but e.Data is null alltime.

Comment: @user1950843 This event fires even without text output sometimes. If you really see the output as you said in the comment, so it will be not null at some time. Instead of breakpoint write e.Data to the file.

Comment: I'm write to file but it's empty. Maybe problem in OS? I have Windows 8 Enterprise(with installed updates). Maybe this code will be work in Windows XP, but it's too old OS.

Comment: @user1950843 so one more time. You run your game from the command line, for example C:\Program Files\MyGame>mygame.exe . Do you see the desired output in the same command line?

Comment: No, i see desired output in new window that create a game.

Comment: @user1950843 well, I'm also interested if it's possible to catch output from custom window, will vote on your question

Comment: I'm found interesting web pages:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx
Will be research tomorrow. Currently i'm tired.